# How did Martha and Jonathan Kent have the information needed to take care of Superman?

Tags: dc, superman

When Superman’s human parents first encountered Superman at the crash site, he was an infant. It can be inferred from the comics that Superman is able to eat human food normally even though this would contradict how his biology is depicted as using solar power only. However, Martha and Jonathan Kent should not have known this fact since there was no information on Superman’s race available to them. Furthermore, they are somehow able to guide him through infancy and childhood despite the lack of basic knowledge about his species.

Is there a canonical explanation for how Jonathan and Martha Kent could have acquired the knowledge at the time they found him?

Comment: He can eat [pretty much anything](https://www.cbr.com/superman-weirdest-things-eaten/) and you can bounce him like a basketball all day without harming him. At that point, good parenting basically boils down to dealing with his *emotional* needs.

Comment: Maybe use species instead of race. For all they knew, the baby was a white male human.

Comment: I remember seeing a comic from the 1950s showing the pediatrician holding a syringe with bent needle after trying to vaccinate him.  Did the doctor or the Kents freak out and call the authorities?  No.  Why?  Because **stop overthinking comic books!!!**

Comment: i think he acted much like other babies -- maybe ate despite, on Earth, not needing to. an image i recall is the baby superman lifting heavy furniture.

Comment: Kal El was fired off _in the knowledge_ that he would essentially be the sole survivor (other fringe cases were not considered when he was being shot into space). Was it ever explicitly mentioned that no baby book made it into that escape pod? That's be the first thing I thought of if I were to fire my son towards a different alien race that just happens to look alike enough that he could assimilate and be one of them even though their biology is radically different.

Comment: @Flater In Man of Steel #6 it was shown that Jor-EL had left an advanced  hologram of himself that would give information about Kal's origin if needed. It is not mentioned but we can guess it would be informing any presumed foster parents too if it encountered them. Unfortunately the hologram was damaged in  the crash and didn't activate until Superman was an adult.

Comment: When  It can be inferred from the comics that Superman is able to eat human food normally, what more did the Kents need? Special knowledge about nappy changing, or what?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

They initially believed that the baby they found was human and raised him accordingly. Fortunately, the needs of a Kryptonian baby were similar enough to those of a human one for it to work.

From Man of Steel #1 (1986)
[image]

Comment: In the current versions of the story, he's interfertile with a human woman, which seemingly makes Kryptonians (and presumably their offshoots like Phaelosians and Daxamites) a subspecies of *homo sapiens*.